# nginx の alias指定で phpMyAdmin に接続する時の File Not Found エラーの解消法

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx, phpmyadmin

CakePHP を動作させる際に phpMyAdmin を設定する際のことに関して質問です。

環境：

- CentOS6
- PHP 5.5
- CakePHP 2.6.0

でやっています。

```
/var/www/phpmyadmin/
```

に alias 指定でアクセスさせるために質問後半に示すような設定ファイルを書いた結果

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

でアクセスすることはできたんですが、

```
File not Found
```

が出てしまいます…  
読み込ませるにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

以下 `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` に記載した設定

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    #中略
    location /phpmyadmin {
         alias /var/www/phpmyadmin;
         index index.php;

         location ~ \.php$ {
                  root /var/www/phpmyadmin;
                  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                  fastcgi_index index.php;
                  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                  include fastcgi_params;
         }
    }

    #中略

    #CakePHPのURLリライティング設定
    location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index  index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: 「root /var/www/hpmyadmin;」の部分、p が抜けていますが、問題ありませんか？

Comment: pが抜けているのは記載ミスでした…
しかし、同様にアクセスした場合でも
    File not found
になります。

Comment: Nginx のログファイル「/var/log/nginx/error.log」(デフォルト)にエラーメッセージが記録されていると思われます。それを追記していただけますか？

Comment: こちらになります。
    *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。つまり、document root の設定を「location ~ \.php$ { ...」の内部で行っていることが原因ですね。。。後は、abebe さんと hinaloe さんの回答の通りです。

Comment: CakePHPと同居させなくてはいけない事を見逃していました。CakePHP本体はどこにインストールされていますか？もし/var/www直下に配置されているとしたら、Cakeのルーティングとバッティングしてハマる可能性があるので、nginxのコンフィグはバーチャルホストで分離する方法をオススメします。

Comment: こちらありがとうございます。
現在Cakeと同居させるところでハマっております。

>バーチャルホストで分離する方法をオススメします。
この点ご教授いただけますでしょうか？

Comment: Cake本体は 
  
  `/var/www/html/cakephp`

に設置しております。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHPとphpMyAdiminをバーチャルホストで分離してみました。CakePHPを`http://localhost/`で、phpMyAdminを`http://localhost:8080`でアクセスできるようにしています。

```
# phpMyAdmin
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    root   /var/www/phpmyadmin;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

# CakePHP
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root   /var/www/html/cakephp/webroot/;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

### 動作確認

- nginx 1.6.2
- CakePHP 2.6.0
- phpMyAdmin 4.3.4

### 参考URL

[CakePHP Cookbook 2.x ドキュメント - nginxでのきれいなURL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/installation/url-rewriting.html#nginxurl)

Comment: こちらありがとうございます。
一点質問がございます。
abebeさんの通りに

     `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'

を書き換えた場合、phpmyadminのログイン画面まで表示されましたが、DcumentRootを変更認めにCakeにアクセスできなくなりました。
DocumentRootにアクセスした場合に

    `404 not found`

が表示されます。
また、

    `location ~ \.php {
        root /var/www/html/cakephp/app/webroot;
    }`

とPHPを読み込む部分でcakeのwebrootにDocumentRootに合わせるとphpmyadminにアクセスできなくなります。

    `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

でcakeとphpmyadminにアクセスさせるにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: 分離したパターンに変更してみました。これでphpMyAdmin/CakePHP共に依存せずアクセス可能になると思います。

Comment: 出来ました！！！
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2):

[Nginx での location 優先順位まとめ - tkuchikiの日記](http://tkuchiki.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/01/30/191604)によると修飾子なしの前方一致は優先順位が一番低く、`location ~ \.php$`が優先されているものかと思われます。

とりあえず正常に動作してるAmimotoを参考に、Cake用のlocationディレクティブを`location /`で囲ってみるといいかもしれません。

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    #中略
    location /phpmyadmin {
         alias /var/www/phpmyadmin;
         index index.php;
         #中略
    }

    #中略

    #CakePHPのURLリライティング設定
    location / {
        location ~ \.php$ {
             fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index  index.php;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```